# Do schedule Apex stop running if there is an exception?

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

1. Do Schedule Apex execute method stop running if there is an exception (normal exception) ?
2. Do Schedule Apex execute method stop running if there is an exception (exception has occurred in a batch called) ?
3. What if there are batch jobs executed successfully prior to the above exception, do they roll back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do Schedule Apex execute method stop running if there is an exception (normal exception) ?

Assuming it is an unhandled exception, then yes. Any pending actions, such as a queued Batchable classes, will also be rolled back. The job status for the Schedulable class will show the error.

> Do Schedule Apex execute method stop running if there is an exception (exception has occurred in a batch called) ?

No. Batches are a separate transaction, and will not throw an exception back to the Schedulable class. The Schedulable job will show as completed.

> What if there are batch jobs executed successfully prior to the above exception, do they roll back?

Each `execute` method can fail independently of other `execute` methods. Those that finish successfully will have their data committed, those that throw an uncaught exception will have their data rolled back. Once a transaction is fully committed, it cannot be rolled back. The job status will show the number of batches that failed, as well as the first error message.